# Can reactive current in an AC circuit dissipate through another resistive load which is connected parallel in same circuit?

Tags: reactive-power

Two loads are connected in parallel to an AC circuit, one is inductive and the other is purely resistive. As per the nature of an inductive load, it will return the reactive power at end of each half cycle to source. So, when this reactive current flows from load to source can it flow through the resistive load which is connected in parallel to it and dissipates the reactive power? If the answer is NO then, how to understand this analogy?

Answer (score 1):

There are many way you can see it, but the simplest way in my mind is seeing your load as a single one with a complex impedance. If so, you only have one load that is slightly inductive.

The way you seem to look at it is with the theorem of superposition. It's not the best way to visualize it since your inductor isn't really a source. It's only a phase shift between your voltage and current.